# How to add active directory with sharepoint in the Virtual server?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

I have a main server with windows server 2008 with active directory installed. Additionally, I have created the hyper-v virtual server with MOSS 2007 installed with dynamic ip address. I can access the sharepoint site as an intranet.

How can I assign the access of all the active directory users and their profile to MOSS without adding them up manually ?

If I am missing any information to provide please mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set up an AD import on your SharePoint server. Take a look at [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263382.aspx).
Or this TechNet video: [How Do I: Configure the Active Directory Profile Import Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/dd979038.aspx).